# Hive simple Regular expression

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to check if all data within in a column is having a valid date.

```
create table dates (tm string, dt string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'

date.txt(sample data)
20181205    15
20171023    23
20170516    16

load data local inpath 'dates.txt' overwrite into table dates;

create temporary macro isitDate(s string)
case when regexp_extract(s,'((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])',0) = '' 
     then false 
     else true 
end;

select * from dates where isitDate(dt);
```

But select statement is giving below error-

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   Unable to execute method public java.lang.String
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
>   on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract@66b45e1e of
>   class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with arguments
>   {15:java.lang.String, ((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]):java.lang.String,
>   0:java.lang.Integer} of size 3

Is there something wrong with my regular expression.

Comment: what is the exact date format you were trying to match here, is it 20181205 like this ?, then i dont think the regex you were using is sufficient enough.

Comment: I am interested in checking values of second column only, whether these are valid dates or not(Between 01 and 31)

Answer (score 0):

made a stupid mistake, there is one extra opening bracket in macro

Comment: You should delete the question.